# Getting Matterjs Element

Tags: node.js, matter.js

I looked up a matterjs rectangle object and noticed an id. Is there is any way to retrieve the rectangle object by that id?

Object Data Example:

```
id:5
type:body
label:Rectangle Body
parts:Array
plugin:Object
angle:0
vertices:Array
position:Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
Matter.Composite.get(composite, id, type);
```

More information: https://brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Composite.html#method_get